# How many k-digit numbers ending with zero(s) are there?

Tags: combinatorics

We have a $k$-digit non-negative number in base $B$ (let's treat all k-digit numbers as valid, so that for example if $k=5$ and base $10$ all numbers from $00000$ to $99999$ are perfectly fine).

How many numbers are there that end with one or more $0$?

The answer is $B^{k-1}-1$, but I can't really figure out why.

Comment: Let $B=10$ and $k=2$. Let's list them all: $00,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90$, a total of $10$. The formula quoted gives $9$. Either the formula is wrong or the problem is not stated exactly.

Comment: The formula would be good for positive integers, and is out by one for non-negative integers.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first solve it for arbitrary sequences of with values in $\{0,\dots,B-1\}$.  Then clearly there is a bijection between sequences of length $k$ ending in $0$ and sequences of length $k-1$, and we know there are $B^{k-1}$ instances of the latter.  Now you want only sequences denoting non-negative numbers, so $0^k$ is no longer an option, but that's the only sequence that you forbid, so the answer is $B^{k-1}-1$.

Edit: @mvw is right, I mistook non-negative for positive.  So if you really mean non-negative, I can't explain the answer either.

Comment: The alternative answer says there are $(B-1)(1+B+...+B^{k-2})=B^{k-1}-1 = B^{k-1}-1$ such numbers. How to interpret that? Is it something like: the digit to the left before one or more ending zeros can take $B-1$ values. And then digits to the left can take any value (multiplication principle).

Comment: Seems like we group together the sequences with exactly $i$ zeros at the end for $i<k$.  So for such a sequence we have the digit just before the zeros can take $B-1$ values and for the rest we have $B^{k-i-1}$ possibilities.  This gives the sum in your answer, but again, our presumption was that we do not count $0$ as a valid sequence (which would be the case $i=k$).

Answer (score 0):

You count from $0$ to $B^k - 1$. Those are $B^k$ numbers.

$$
(n)_{10} = (d_{k-1}\cdots d_0).
$$

Every $1$ in $10$ has a $0$ digit at the end ($d_0 = 0$). So these are $B^k / B = B^{k-1}$ numbers.

It is probably that plain $0$ is not considered to have a $0$ at the end, otherwise I do not see why the result is one less.

Or you mean positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are $B$ options for each of the $k$ digits, the the total number of numbers is $B^{k}$. Of these, there are $B^{k-1}(B-1)$ numbers whose last digit is not 0, so subtracting yields $B^{k-1}$, the number of numbers with at least 1 trailing zero. Assuming we discard the number 0 in base $B$, the answer follows.